# convert string representation of timespan to timespan object

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have strings like those for example:
'1 hour'
'5 mins'
'1 day'
'30 secs'
'4 hours'

this strings represent the time past since something.
I want to convert them to the time (DateTime) that it happends

I tried to insert it to a timespan.parse but it throw an exception...

What is the best way to do something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Show us your code and the exception you got.

Comment: you can split your each string with space and represent it as
string str ="1:05:30:" and then parse it.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself correctly each of those strings is by its own. They are not related to each other. I can have a string like this: '5 min' ant i want to convert it to timespan

Comment: You can split the string and use dictionary for all the names ("hour", "hours", "min", "mins" etc)

Answer (score 2):

You may try using *Dictionary* for all the *names* are used:

```
public static TimeSpan ParseTimeSpan(String value) {
  // Expand dictionary with values you're using, e.g. 
  // "second", "minute", "week" etc.
  Dictionary<String, long> seconds = new Dictionary<String, long>() {
    {"days", 86400},
    {"day", 86400},
    {"hours", 3600},
    {"hour", 3600},
    {"mins", 60},
    {"min", 60},
    {"secs", 1},
    {"sec", 1}
  };

  String[] items = value.Split();

  long result = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < items.Length - 1; i += 2)
    result += long.Parse(items[i]) * seconds[items[i + 1]];

  return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(result);
}

... 

TimeSpan result = ParseTimeSpan("1 hour 15 mins 32 secs");
```

Comment: my answer feels so oversimplified after this... =(

Answer (score 0):

The second part in the string is *units*.

Dunno about format what you will have, but all those listead can be split and parsed like this:

```
// text is "1 hour" or "5 mins" or "1 day" or "30 secs" or "4 hours"
var item = text.Split(new char[] {' '});
var value = int.Parse(item[0]);
var unit = item[1];
// get lowest units, in our case it is seconds
if(unit.StartWith("min"))
    value *= 60;
else
    if(unit.StartWith("hour"))
        value *= 60 * 60;
    else
        if(unit.StartWith("day"))
            value *= 60 * 60 * 24;
// now that we have seconds, we can convert it into timespan
var timespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, value);
```

You could do it for *ms* or even *ticks*.

Answer (score 0):

```
        string strResultTime = "5 hours";

        //The function that gets the time and converts it to seconds
        MatchEvaluator evaluator = new MatchEvaluator(ConvertToSeconds);


        strResultTime = Regex.Replace(strResultTime, "(?<num>\\d+?) (?<timeUnit>.+)", evaluator);

        //Parse the seconds to an actual datetime.
        DateTime indexTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(int.Parse(strResultTime) * -1);


    /// <summary>
    /// Converts strings if format 'X time' like '2 mins' or '5 hours' to the time that they represents in seconds
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="mchTime">Match that contains '2 mins' and Groups["timeUnit"] = 'hour' or other time unit AND Groups["num"] = the number of that time unit</param>
    /// <returns>The number of seconds as string</returns>
    private string ConvertToSeconds(Match mchTime)
    {
        //Switch on the time unit
        switch (mchTime.Groups["timeUnit"].Value)
        {
            case "day":
            case "days":
                //Return the number of days as seconds
                return (int.Parse(mchTime.Groups["num"].Value) * 24 * 60 * 60).ToString();
            case "hour":
            case "hours":
                //Return the number of hours as seconds
                return (int.Parse(mchTime.Groups["num"].Value) * 60 * 60).ToString();
            case "min":
            case "mins":
                //Return the number of mins as seconds
                return (int.Parse(mchTime.Groups["num"].Value) * 60).ToString();
            case "sec":
            case "secs":
                return mchTime.Groups["num"].Value;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime.Parse has an overloaded version that allows you to pass an `IFormatProvider`. Creating a class that implements `IFormatProvider` to convert your strings how you want them parsed, and pass an instance of this class to `TimeSpan.Parse` as a second argument. This would be the approach I would take.
```

Answer (score -2):

Use string like "1:5" with [TimeSpan.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3z48198e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Is there anything wrong with this answer? Correct me or explain how the vote down comes.

Comment: I want somehow to convert strings like the examples to timespan... What is the "1:5" you wrote? BTW I didn't vote.

Comment: They should add a possibility to see downvoters names (to downvote them in turn obviously!). It could be, what your answer doesn't solve even a single case of OP question (while there is voted up comment, which has missing in your answer part *represent*). /shrug

Comment: Jay, did you check the MSDN link I attached? There are examples there.